# Joining tables in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4

I have a table called Students and a table called Majors, Students and Majors are joined by `MajorId`  I have set this relationship already and have set the foreign key in the schema.  When I access my `Student` object how can I return the `MajorName` column (this comes from the Majors table)?  The only options I have in intellisense is `Major_1`, `Major_1Reference`, `MajorId` .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051612/entity-framework-join-3-tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Major_1` should be a navigation property leading to the appropriate `Major` entry, so you should be able to access the `Major`'s properties like this:

```
from s in ctx.Students
select s.Major_1.MajorName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq join statement like this to make query on the two tables...

```
var q = from s in Students
        join m in Majors on s.MajorId  equals m.MajorId 
        select new { m.MajorName };
```